# Contexts and notations for composing asymmetric simplices

Tags: universal-algebra, notation, simplicial-complexes

Imagine the elements of a group-like structure as **puzzle pieces** with essential two sides, an IN-side and an OUT-side.

[image]

You can compose two such pieces in two obvious ways:

[image]

Now consider triangular puzzle pieces with at least one IN- and one OUT-side. These are 2-**simplices** with a non-trivial partition of their sides.

[image]

As long as two sides of the same kind are not distinguished (i.e. the simplices are symmetric), there are again two ways to compose two such pieces:

[image]

[image]

But when two sides of the same kind are distinguished:

[image]

a single operator + doesn't suffice anymore. One has to specify which of the (eventually) two OUT-sides of the first piece is to be plugged into which of the (eventually) two IN-sides of the second piece:

[image]

I wonder:

> **(1) In which specific (algebraic or simplicial resp. topological) contexts do such asymmetric pieces appear?**
>
> (2) How then is the problem of notation solved, especially: how are "words" (conglomerates) of such pieces symbolically written down (which is trivial for group-like structures and symmetric simplices by the use of + or $\circ$ or even no symbol at all).

Note that the composition is supposed to be in a natural way **associative**.

A related question concerns the possibility that **cycles** are allowed.

[image]

For group-like structures, cycles are *not* allowed (and in the rigid picture of puzzle pieces cycles are not even *possible*), for simplex-based structures cycles are supposed to *be* allowed:

> (3) How is the problem of notation solved for possibly circular conglomerates?

Comment: I do not understand why you identify the two ways of sticking symmetric triangles together in your fourth picture. Both give rise to different arrangements if you add further triangles.

Comment: True enough! But regarding piece B as a symmetric one you cannot distinguish the two arrangements - with respect to B. That's what I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an attempt. Not a full answer, rather a suggestion of an approach.

Instead of triangles let us look at nodes with three strings coming out of them. So, for the triangle of type "A" let us write

[image]

and for the triangle of type "B" let us write

[image]

The bottom line is that the strings that go upwards from the node correspond to OUT-sides, and strings that go downwards from the node correspond to IN-sides. Let us regard these pictures as string diagrams http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+diagram. Then we can compose them as we compose string diagrams. Some of the possible compositions are:

[image]

We allow strings to intersect each other (as is the case in the leftmost diagram). Such compositions should correspond to the "triangle compositions". So as the leftmost diagram above is "A1 + 0B", the second diagram is "A1 + 1B" and the third diagram is "B + A" as in OP.

Triangle tilings which are obtained inductively by adjoining one tile by a single edge at a time are representable by string diagrams. On the other hand, a tiling can be constructed from a string diagram that has no cycles. These can be shown by induction on number of tiles/nodes. I believe that there is a one-to-one correspondence between tilings and string diagrams of these types.

For more complicated tilings things get more difficult. Anyway, the "cycle" in the OP would be

[image]

After this category theory and string diagrams tell us how to solve the problem of notation. We can imagine that we are inside a symmetric monoidal category where we have an object $X$ and two morphisms $f : X\otimes X \rightarrow X$ and $g : X \rightarrow X\otimes X$ corresponding to the triangles "A" and "B" respectively (more concretely say that we are in the symmetric monoidal category free on such a data). Then the notation comes from the string calculus for a symmetric monoidal category. Thus for example, "A1 + 0B" would be the composite

$$X\otimes X \xrightarrow{1_X\otimes g} X\otimes X\otimes X \xrightarrow{s\otimes 1_X} X\otimes X\otimes X \xrightarrow{1_X\otimes f} X\otimes X,$$

where $s$ stands for the symmetry of the monoidal category.

Comment: Does every such diagram yield a legal two-dimensional arrangement of tiles? If not, can you see from the diagrams if they can be realised in 2d without actually constructing realisations?

Comment: No they don't. The answer is perhaps only a suggestion of an approach. In fact, I don't know if more complicated planar diagrams can be represented by diagrams.

Comment: @Sebastian See my last edit too.

Comment: @Dimitri: Thanks, sounds promising.